# How to edit extensions git URL in www.civicrm.org/extensions

Tags: extension, civicrm.org

We are moving the main repository of one of our public extensions. 
How do we edit the git url in an existing node in www.civicrm.org/extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're logged in to civicrm.org, find your extension's listing in the search, then on your extension page click the Edit tab. You can also edit the name, development status and description.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue of the new www.civcrm.org website, but Edit Tab is not displayed in the extension node, after I log in. And I think it's a permissions issue in Drupal, after finding the node Id, I tried to access by URL (https://civicrm.org/node/<nid>/edit) and got "Access denied"

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. Are you sure the extension was added by the same account you are logged in as? (Or that you're listed as a maintainer of the extension, you can name extra maintainers who should also be able to edit it)

Comment: No, I cannot edit any extension node I created nor logged in as the maintainers as well.

Comment: Might be a good idea to send them an email at info@civicrm.org then.